# Drawing a rotated image on top of another image

Tags: c#, graphics, rotatetransform

I'm attempting to draw an image that was rotated on top of another image, but I can't manage to align both images in the center. (i.e. draw the rotated image in the middle of the first, untouched image)

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(firstImage);
// Rotate from the center
g.TranslateTransform((float)firstImage.Width / 2, (float)firstImage.Height / 2);
g.RotateTransform(angle);
// Return to the original coordinates
g.TranslateTransform(-((float)firstImage.Width / 2), -((float)firstImage.Height / 2));
g.DrawImage(secondImage, 0, 0);
```

Is there a way to center the second image on the first image?

Both images are of the same size (200x200).

Comment: That works perfectly for me.  Can you show a screenshot and/or give more details?...

Comment: Could you give us a snapshot? This also works perfectly for me. Are you joking?

Comment: Hmm, weird, going to double check my code tomorrow since I  don't have a machine with Visual Studio at home.

Comment: Found the problem - apparently when you convert the `Image` to `Bitmap`, the converted `Bitmap` is of the wrong/re-sized size for some reason.